# How to replace app engine modelclass.properties() with Django functions?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am looking at the challenges in converting a codebase from using [app engine patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) to using [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel).

One of the things that happens in this codebase several times is iterating over all properties of an entity.  For example, comparator, copy constructor, __str__ equivalent, and so on.

Simplified example:

```
def compare_things(thing_a, thing_b):
  '''Compare two things on properties not in Thing.COMPARE_IGNORE_PROPS'''
  if type(thing_a) != type(thing_b): return "Internal error"

  for prop in Thing.properties():
    if prop not in Thing.COMPARE_IGNORE_PROPS:
      attr_a = getattr(thing_a, prop)
      attr_b = getattr(thing_b, prop)
      if attr_a != attr_b:
        return prop + ": " + str(attr_a) + " is not equal to " + str(attr_b)
  return ''
```

However, the properties() function is from google.appengine.ext.db.Model.

If I wish to use django-nonrel, all my model objects will be instead from django.db.models.Model.

Is there an equivalent functionality in that class?

Answer (score 0):

I went to sleep and woke up with an approximate answer.  One can use dir to loop over the class members.  Something like (untested):

```
from django.db import models

def properties(model_class):
  ret = []
  for name in dir(model_class):
    thing = getattr(model_class, name)
    if (isinstance(thing, models.Field)):
      ret.append(name)
  return ret
```